# Get a row based on other two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

For an instance we have these three tables:

**terms_relation**

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ post_id ║ term_id ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║       1 ║       1 ║
║       1 ║       2 ║
║       1 ║       3 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

**terms_taxonomy**

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ term_id ║ taxonomy ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║       1 ║ categ    ║
║  2 ║       2 ║ categ    ║
║  3 ║       3 ║ tag      ║
║  4 ║       3 ║ categ    ║
║  5 ║       4 ║ categ    ║
║  6 ║       5 ║ tag      ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

**terms**

```
╔════╦════════╦════════╗
║ id ║  name  ║  slug  ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ samsung║ samsung║
║  2 ║ nokia  ║ nokia  ║
║  3 ║ opera  ║ opera  ║
║  4 ║ chrome ║ chrome ║
║  5 ║ webkit ║ webkit ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╝
```

When `terms_relation.post_id = 1`, How do I select all rows in `terms` which has a `taxonomy` of `categ` in `terms_taxonomy` based on `term_id`?

So it has to get: `samsung`,`nokia` (not `opera` because it is a tag).

Here's my current try, unfortunately I do not understand what's wrong with my query:

```
select terms.name from terms_taxonomy 
join terms_relation 
on terms_relation.post_id = 1
join terms
on terms_taxonomy.term_id = terms.id
where taxonomy = "categ"
```

undesired output of query above:

```
+---------+
| name    |
+---------+
| samsung |
| nokia   |
| opera   |
| chrome  |
| samsung |
| nokia   |
| opera   |
| chrome  |
| samsung |
| nokia   |
| opera   |
| chrome  |
| samsung |
| nokia   |
| opera   |
| chrome  |
| samsung |
| nokia   |
| opera   |
| chrome  |
| samsung |
| nokia   |
| opera   |
| chrome  |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just move the condition inside the `JOIN`. Also, moving the `post_id` condition inside the WHERE seems more logical:

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM terms_relation tr
JOIN terms_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_id = tt.term_id AND tt.taxonomy = "categ"
JOIN terms t ON tr.term_id = tt.id
WHERE tr.post_id = 1
```

**Edit** I reread your question again and couldn't really figure out how the relationships are defined, I assumed these join conditions:

- terms_taxonomy.term_id = terms_relation.term_id
- terms.id = terms_taxonomy.term_id

Comment: yes the three are related, it's still getting `opera` though.

Comment: `terms.id = terms_taxonomy.term_id`

Comment: Changed the query to have `terms.id = terms_taxonomy.id` - that's probably more likely what you want then.

Comment: `terms_taxonomy.id` is not related to `terms.id`.

Comment: But for `terms_taxonomy` table where `id = 4` you have `term_id = 3` and `taxonomy = 'categ'` so that should show opera ... I'm confused now :)

Comment: Ah, yeah it should get the three! LoL how could I not see that. Thanks!

Comment: @JackSpairow phew, I thought I was going crazy haha!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version without joins:

```
SELECT name FROM terms WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id FROM terms_taxonomy,terms_relation,terms
 WHERE terms_relation.post_id = 1 
 AND terms_taxonomy.taxonomy = "categ" 
 AND terms.id = terms_taxonomy.term_id);
```

Comment: The output was: `samsung, nokia, chrome, webkit`

Comment: Edited to match terms_taxonomy.term_id to term.id like the other answer. Should work now.